# Asp.net validation expression for a string

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to create a regular expression for subdomain like:

In the textbox user need to enter like

```
abc1.test.com
```

or

```
abc1s.test.com
```

Note: **.test.com** is always required at the end.

The variable part can contain any letter, alphabets etc

I dont know anything about regex so i ask this silly question. I googled it for more than 2 hours but dont find any good example.

Please note this is not a homework.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should probably *re-phrase* the qusetion title...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of useful resources on regex online, including:

- http://regexpal.com/ - test out your regex
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html - regex reference
- http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/ - useful cheat sheet

I am sure other members will have better resources but these have sufficed for me in the past.

The following regex should work for you:

```
^((.+)(.test.com){1})$
```

- the '.' is any character except new line
- the '+' is one or more times
- the '{1}' is exactly once

Comment: `{1}` is not required. A literal repeats itself once by default. You will need to escape the `.` since a `.` is a meta character. Your regex would match `abcstestlcom`. A cleaner and correct regex is `^[\d\w]+\.test\.com$`

Answer (score 1):

```
^[\d\w]+\.test\.com$ will work for your case.
```